# Hazelcast Run.bat stuck at "Starting .."

Tags: hazelcast

I am using hazelcast 1.9.4 version...
I started run.bat from the bin directory, but it doesn't seem to be started..

Mar 8, 2012 11:46:38 AM com.hazelcast.impl.LifecycleServiceImpl
INFO: /10.50.26.189:5704 [dev] Address[10.50.26.189:5704] is STARTING--->  It stuck here..

Any idea what would have gone wrong.!

Answer (score 1):

I see that your member started with port 5704? It may be that some of the members that you previously started were not properly shutdown. Make sure that you don't have any hanging java(running hazelcast) process.

Answer (score 0):

Exit already running Hazelcast nodes . (this seems to be the fourth node :5704)The other nodes might have crashed.
Restarting Hazelcast should fix your problem.!